# How to infer object keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an object by iterating through an array and only picking the elements that I need. An example will make this clearer:

```
const items = [{ type: 'foo' }, { type: 'bar' }, { type: 'baz' }] as const

type MyItems = {
  foo: string | null
  bar: string | null
}

const myItems: MyItems = {
  foo: null,
  bar: null,
}

items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.type in myItems) {
    item.type
      // ^? (property) type: "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
  }

  if (Object.keys(myItems).includes(item.type)) {
    item.type
      // ^? (property) type: "foo" | "bar" | "baz"
  }
})
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA2gbxlATwAdEAuGAcgDMQQKYBfAGhj0JPIoCMBDAJ3rNW%20YmUq8AXoIC6MHmlCQoAKFXL2iGAFkCASSSoMrZTBg0Q5aHzhgA5jAA%20MMAFcANm5MxefS1Gt2js7ungyqitAwyHoGEOQ6%20ihomDhe5uSuHkxePhkh2WHKCEkAdDR8AKI8wAAWABTFyBgAfMamcFQwDQYlGvBgUTFJAJRtpvA9Gl7jMAD0szAAegD8XoXtnXUA8lwAVojAUCUA1ogEEHXRiajDJTbAbi4AJogXjb2iw6OpM%209TM6Z5ktVqYwgxhkA)

My real life example is more complexe and I can't simply reduce on `items`.

My issue is that TypeScript doesn't infer properly on item.type after the condition and I don't know how to fix this other that with an `as` that I'd rather not use if possible.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards)

```js
const pickByMyItems = 
  <T extends (typeof items)[number]>(item: T): item is Extract<T, { type: keyof typeof myItems }> => 
    Object.keys(myItems).includes(item.type)
```

to filter the items before iterating them:

```js
items.filter(pickByMyItems).forEach(item => {
  if (item.type in myItems) {
    item.type
      // ^? (property) type: "foo" | "bar"
  }

  if (Object.keys(myItems).includes(item.type)) {
    item.type
      // ^? (property) type: "foo" | "bar"
  }
})
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA2gbxlATwAdEAuGAcgDMQQKYBfAGhj0JPIoCMBDAJ3rNW+YmUq8AXoIC6MHmlCQoAKFXL2iGAFkCASSSoMrZTBg0Q5aHzhgA5jAA+MMAFcANm5MxefS1Gt2js7ungyqitAwyHoGEOQ6+ihomDhe5uSuHkxePhkh2WHKCEkAdDR8AKI8wAAWABTFyBgAfMamcFQwDQYlGvBgUTFJAJRtpvA9Gl7jAPQzMAB6APxehe2ddQDyXABWiMBQJQDWiAQQddGJqMMlNsBuLgAmiOeNvaLDo6njEyjvJNNZvNlqtlAxhuFwJEiHBgEcAEIEBKxIwAHgAKjBEAAPJBgR5oOoaECdRoQYZYVzILiIPjSZrdFDkdHDciNeBoCq4vjVKAYlhsUTkE4EEkiEhiy4ohitdCtbZ7A7HU7nKUjW5ge5PF6M5D-RAQ1RkspwNxIPh1GFwxHI9XlKq1XUtMYdLpvPo2QZXcljdqTUSA0xzRYrUxreAbBX7Q4i1VDa4arXPV7+kifX2-PVTH5B4GhxhgiFAA)

--

you can as well use it in an if condition

```
items.forEach(item => {
  if (pickByMyItems(item)) {
    item.type
      // ^? (property) type: "foo" | "bar"
  }
})
```